# Grounding the components of a DIY cnc machine

Tags: grounding, interference, cnc, star

I'm in the process of building a DIY cnc machine. It already runs, but I noticed it has some interference problems (steppers act weird on occasions, the [full graphic smart controller LCD](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Full-Graphic-Smart-Controller-LCD-Display-for-RAMPS-1-4-RepRap-3D-Printer-Electronics-12864-display/32852039927.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.1.586521cczzkCgk&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3_10065_10068_319_10059_10884_317_10887_10696_321_322_453_10084_454_10083_10103_10618_10304_10307_10820_10301_10821_537_536_10902,searchweb201603_51,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=acb8c686-6746-457f-8cab-0633f4c7b818-0&algo_pvid=acb8c686-6746-457f-8cab-0633f4c7b818) has trouble displaying the contents), due to the [noisy chinese spindle](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/500W-Air-Cooled-Spindle-ER11-CNC-Spindle-Motor-Kit-Adjustable-Power-Supply-52MM-Clamps-ER11-Collet/32864211347.html?af=cc&aff_platform=aaf&cpt=1549819925935&sk=6mia6uv&aff_trace_key=b556561d502f4e4fb3bf20ce24caecc2-1549819925935-08981-6mia6uv&terminal_id=74b813a8a84f4cbdb91d32a3681052c2) I'm using. To remedy this, I've read I should ground everything in a star-like topology.

The hardware consists of a 12V chinese PSU which connects to an Arduino Mega with Ramps 1.6 and 3 DRV8825 drivers. There is also a spindle controller, which generates the noise and doesn't have the ground symbol. I was told on another forum, that since it doesn't have an earth symbol, I should just tie the earth to one screw of the chassis. The PSU and the spindle controller are connected to an extension socket.

I'm using shielded cable to connect to the stepper motors from Ramps, but the cable is also not grounded yet (just found out it has to be).

Can somebody describe how does a star-like topology look in my case? I've also read, I should ground the motor drivers, but I can't seem to find anything on the internet regarding this.

Thank you.

The 12V PSU:

[image]

The spindle controller:

[image]

The Arduino Mega/Ramps board and DRV8825 stepper drivers (I know dupont cables and isolation tape should't be used in this case. I'll replace them promptly):
[image]

Stepper driver and signal cable connection (the shielded signal cables are not grounded yet):
[image]

Comment: Why is there no mains earth on the PSU chassis in photo 1? The terminal is there because the connection is required for your safety.

Comment: I know this is considered a death sin, but I'm trying to ground everything now. Hence this question.